Unit of force used in UUV Simulator
I am building my AUV dynamics model with UUVSimulator. There is something wrong when it comes to the thrust configuration. What is the unit of thrust, N or kg?

Thrust is a force. The SI unit of force is newtons (N) and

represents the amount needed to accelerate 1 kilogram of mass at the rate of 1 meter per second per second.

Therefore it should be safe to assume that UUVSimulator uses SI units, and hence newtons, for thrust.
